# dispatch_once invalidate the NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

Here is my sample code..i have Timer for every seconds to fire function "call".

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(call:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"sdfsf",@"wsdf", nil] repeats:YES];


-(void)call :(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSLog(@"called outside %@",timer.userInfo);
   static dispatch_once_t myDisPatch;
    dispatch_once(&myDisPatch, ^{
        NSLog(@"called inside");
    });
```

}

Here my doubt is, when we change "static dispatch_once_t  myDisPatch" into "dispatch_once_t  myDisPatch". Then timer Automatically invalidated.It wont again call the function. why it happen when i remove static keyword from dispatch_once_t ? why it stops the timer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't stopping your timer. Instead when you remove the static keyword it is blocking the main thread in a wait trap (it stays here forever).

Click pause in the debugger when you expect your timer to be fired, you will see the stack trace.

[image]

[image]

If you want to not use a static dispatch token, assign it with a value of 0 (not sure why you actually need a dispatch_once anyway)

```
dispatch_once_t myDisPatch = 0;
dispatch_once(&myDisPatch, ^{
    NSLog(@"called inside");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static dispatch_once_t myDisPatch;
dispatch_once(&myDisPatch, ^{
    NSLog(@"called inside");
});
```

This is code typically used for singletons to make sure it is only executed exactly once. When you remove the `static`, it can be executed more than once, that's why it works. You should not use this at all for a repeating timer.

So with the static, you will see the "called outside" every second, but the "called inside" only once. That doesn't mean the timer is stopped.

Comment: It doesn't stop the timer.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else, that's why I posted this answer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxsENAwm_XRLblI5VzBibG5ESEk/edit?usp=sharing  Please try this project

Comment: here is my sample project..there you can see the issue.